# Pointer events not triggered on UI Elements in custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, events, uwp, custom-controls

I am creating an application with a `UserControl` containing multiple `UI Elements`. The `UserControl` is rendered into a `StackPanel` using `ItemsControl` since the number of `UserControls` to be rendered depends on user's input.

The basic XAML in the `UserControl` is as follows.

```
<Grid x:Name="Viewport" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Border x:Name="ViewportBorder" Background="White" BorderThickness="2, 2, 2, 2" BorderBrush="#FF353334" />
    <Image x:Name="Image" Margin="0" UseLayoutRounding="True" ManipulationMode="Scale"/>
    <InkCanvas x:Name="InkCanvas" />
    <Canvas x:Name="SelectionCanvas" CompositeMode="SourceOver" />
</Grid>
```

I want to change the cursor icon when user is hovering over the `SelectionCanvas` (based on a condition check in my case as you might see in the source). It seemed pretty straight forward so I tried to use `PointerEntered` & `PointerExited` events to capture & release the pointer from the `SelectionCanvas`. And `PointerMoved` to change the cursor icon. But it seems that none of the events were triggering.

I tried binding to the `Viewport` grid element as well but no luck in that too.

I'm not sure what I missed here. Could someone please help me on this? Any help is much appreciated. Please find the complete source code [here](https://github.com/sparxy3d/uwp-mvvm).

- Please note that a sample PDF is included into the startup project `/Resources` which you'll have to open from the app.

Comment: @mm8's reply should do the work.

Comment: Yeah, it did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PointerEntered` and `PointerExited` events are raised provided that the area that is supposed to raise them is painted so try to set the `Background` property of the `Canvas` to some brush like for example `Transparent`:

```
<Canvas x:Name="SelectionCanvas" CompositeMode="SourceOver"             
        Background="Transparent"             
        PointerEntered="SelectionCanvas_PointerEntered"
        ...
```